# Differences between “en dehors de”, “hors de”, “au-dehors de” and “par-dehors de”?

Tags: prépositions, indications-de-lieu

- *en dehors de*: outside of, apart from
- *hors de*: outside the reach of, out of (figuratively)
- *au-dehors de*: outside of, beyond the border of
- *par-dehors de*: surrounding the outside of

I'm trying to understand the differences in these prepositions when used in the sense of "outside."

Example:

> There is an army outside the city.

- Il y a une armée en dehors de la ville. (outside the city)
- Il y a une armée au-dehors de la ville. (outside the border of the city)
- Il y a une armée hors de la ville. (outside the reach of the city)
- Il y a une armée par-dehors de la ville. (surrounding the outside of the city)

There is not much online explaining these differences. Does this sound right?

Comment: hors de la ville is outside the city too. surrounding is really autour de.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your translations are good.

I'd say "*hors de*" feels closest to *outside*, and "*en dehors*" would be a little bit more like "*on the outside*" (*on the side that is out*). But it's just nitpicking.

**Most importantly**, "*au-dehors*" and above all "*par-dehors*" are **very** old-fashioned.
If I was to utter such a fact, being inside the city, I'd go with:

```
Il y a une armée dehors.
```

Also, "*en dehors*" has a clear opposite, "*en dedans*", that "*hors*" doesn't have (so it might be used for contrast if needed).

Comment: Il y une armée dehors, just means outside the place where you are but not a city.

Answer (score 0):

- *dehors* :  à l'extérieur de ; synonyme de *hors*
- *au-dehors* : à l'extérieur ; synonyme : *extérieurement, loin*
- *en dehors* : ce qui n'est pas *en dedans*.

Comment: There should not be hyphens in "en dehors" and "en dedans", right?

Comment: @angryavian — *au-dehors* ou *au dehors* sont possibles, les autres ont été corrigés, merci de votre remarque. — NB. *dedans* a les mêmes règles de trait d'union que *dehors*.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications!